# GtkComboBox goes outside screen

Tags: drop-down-menu, combobox, gtk, wayland

I have GtkComboBox on top of the screen. When first item is selected, everything is ok, but when I select second or third item, rows 1 and 2 disappear above the screen. Is there a way to make GtkComboBox always popup downwards? (default is that selected item is in the middle). Or is there some another solution?

I am using gtk version 3.22.3 wtih weston-wayland 5.0.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_fullscreen (window);
    
    GtkWidget* vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,0);

    GtkWidget* labelSelector = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
    gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (labelSelector, "first text");
    gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (labelSelector, "second text");
    gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (labelSelector, "third text");
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(labelSelector,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(vbox,labelSelector,0,0,0);

    GtkWidget* button = gtk_button_new_from_icon_name("media-playback start",GTK_ICON_SIZE_DND);
    gtk_box_pack_start(vbox,button,1,1,0);


    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to help here without an explanation what you are doing (e.g. source code). It's also hard to see anything in your images, please use screenshots, snipping tool or something similar for your question's quality sake.

Comment: Hi, I added source code. Unfortunately I can't make a screenshot when comboBox is opened (probably it is a bug in weston).

Comment: I see no reason for coding like that, but trust me that the behavior you noticed there is normal. Any way you if you insinst having a comboboxtext at the top-left of your window, then probably `gtk_combo_box_set_wrap_width ( GTK_COMBO_BOX ( labelSelector ), 3 );` is a good approach.

Comment: Thanks @Michi ! I didn't think of that. That helps me a lot :)